# Match the node if the immediate preceding sibling has a specific name

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I want to select a node if and only if the immediate preceding node has a particular name.For the given xml i want to match with the c node if the node just above it is of the name "a"

**XML**

```
    <root>
    <a name="ABC"\>
    <b\>
    <b name="ABC"\>
    <c\>        
    <root\>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl match ="c and preceding::sibling[a][1]">
```

It is matching the node 'c' having preceding sibling node of the name 'a'. I want it to match only if the **node just above 'c' was 'a'.**

I am fairly new to XSLT and might be perceiving things in the wrong way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not XML. And `<xsl match ="...">` is not XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `c` only if its immediately preceding sibling is `a`, you can use:

```
match="c[name(preceding-sibling::*[1])='a']"
```

or:

```
match="c[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::a]]"
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, It works.Can you explain how "*[1][self::a]]" this works? Just a brief explanation.

Comment: `preceding-sibling::*[1]` selects the immediately preceding sibling. `[self::a]` adds a predicate that is true only if the selected node is `a`.

Comment: Ok, thansk a lot.